# Eclipse RCP/RAP: Can anyone recommend a data-binding framework?

Tags: data-binding, eclipse-rcp

I have been given the task of porting an Access application to Eclipse RCP/RAP. The databases will remain unchanged, just the front-end will be redeveloped.

Having spent some away from eclipse development, I'm wondering what kind of support is available for data-binding to databases. What about controls such as DataGrid (edit/insert/delete rows), multi-line list items and so on?

What frameworks are there? Which ones are still being actively developed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any possibility to bind widgets directly to a database. You'll need to build a Java representation of your database models. Depending on the size of your project, Hibernate or EclipseLink will be preferable to JDBC.

JFace provides [data binding](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/JFace_Data_Binding) that is easy to include into an RCP application. And with [Grid](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php) and [NatTable](http://www.nattable.org/drupal/), there are two SWT implementations of advanced tables available, but I don't know how well they are supported by JFace data binding. Check the [nebula project](http://eclipse.org/nebula/) for other advanced widgets.

Eclipse Riena also provides advanced data binding (by conveniently wrapping JFace), but this is only one of many features. There is an [experimental implementation](http://www.compeople.eu/blog/?p=575) that allows to run Riena applications on [RAP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Riena/RAP_Support).